# jQuery AJAX POST data not getting to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have an AJAX call that is not sending information over to the server from the data parameter. I confirmed it's being recognized as a POST request with my PHP code below. You will notice my `var_dump($_POST)` does not contain the 'myData' data. I'm not sure where to go from here.

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    method : 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url : myURL,    
    data : {
        'myData' : 'myData'
    },  
    async : true,
    success: function (results) {
    console.log('here are the results: ' + results);
},
error: function (req, msg, obj) {
  console.log('An error occured while executing a request');
  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
});
```

PHP

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
echo var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Console.log

```
here are the results: array(1) { ["phpURI"]=> unicode(33) "php/main.php?
function=myFunction" }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$_POST` is auto-filled only if the content-type request header indicates a "multipart/form-data" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" request. For any other content-type you need to parse the raw input data yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Your AJAX request is posting JSON data due to the `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header.

If you just delete that line, `$.ajax` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which should cause PHP to put it into `$_POST` as key-value pairs.